Is there a way to make except ValueError not work for a specific word
from sys import exit

total_sum = 0

try:
    while True:
        print('to stop, write "stop"')
        user_input = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        total_sum = user_input + total_sum
        print("the total number now is:", total_sum)
        if user_input == "stop":
            print("the program has stopped")
            exit()
except ValueError:
    print("please input a valid whole number")

So I made this program, and I would like to know if I can make ValueError not print when I write "stop"
I tried doing except ValueError except "stop". And using not instead of except but it didn't work. I tried rearranging the code so that the "stop" command would be outside of the try: area thing. But then no matter what I did the total_sum wasn't printing but the stop command worked fine.

Maybe put the try inside the loop?

The int call on the input command ensures that only valid numbers will be accepted. If a text value is entered then Python will discard it and raise the exception. So if you are using a string value to terminate the loop you need to change the code to accept a string, and test that before trying to convert it to an integer value.

"i tried doing except ValueError except "stop". and using not instead of except but it didnt work, i tried rearranging the code so that the "stop" command would be outside of the try: area thing" suggests that you could greatly benefit from reading a good tutorial aimed at beginners.

You might want to change your logic: Check for "stop" first, then try to parse the integer value:
from sys import exit

total_sum = 0

while True:
    print('to stop, write "stop"')
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "stop":
        print("the program has stopped")
        exit()
        # One could also use `break` here, as in
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/78852794/7395592
    try:
        total_sum = int(user_input) + total_sum
    except ValueError:
        print("please input a valid whole number")
    else:
        print("the total number now is:", total_sum)

There is no particularly meaningful way to make an "exception from the except", as you try to achieve (if I understand you correctly). Of course, what you could do is look at the message of your ValueError (which, in the case of entering "stop", reads: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'stop'"). So you could parse this message and look for "stop". This, however, is not really how you would use a try-except block usually; the better way would be getting your code's logic right (see above).
To get a better understanding of how exception handling works in Python, maybe have a look at the chapter Errors and Exceptions of Jake VanderPlas's A Whirlwind Tour of Python or any other introductory Python tutorial.

The else after the except block isn't needed

@OneCricketeer If I remove it, it will change the logic, because then "the total number now is:" will also print in case the exception is raised. I could of course include the else part into the try part. But then again, I wanted to make it explicit that the try is only there for the int() parsing. What would you suggest?

You could put a continue in the except block

@OneCricketeer Would that be more readable, more pythonic, or better in any other aspect than the current version?

Your code will look something like:
total_sum = 0
user_input = 0
while True:

    print('to stop, write "stop"')
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "stop":
        break

    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
    except:
        print("please input a valid whole number")
        continue

    total_sum = user_input + total_sum
    print("the total number now is:", total_sum)

print("the program has stopped")

break causes your while loop to terminate, and continue causes your while loop to jump to the next iteration (skipping the rest of the code inside the loop)
But as Andras Deak -- Слава Україні suggested, reading a good tutorial can help you as this is something very beginner in python.

fast and dirty without try/except
while True:
    print('to stop, write "stop"')
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "stop":
        print("the program has stopped")
        exit()
    user_input = int(user_input)
    total_sum = user_input + total_sum
    print("the total number now is:", total_sum)

